# Issue with phonegap local build for android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my phonegap app locally and am incountering the following error

> [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
>
> Error: Invalid attribute name Line: 0 Column: 36 Char: ?
>       at error (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:347:8)
>       at strictFail (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:364:22)
>       at Object.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:876:16)
>       at XMLParser.feed (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
>       at ElementTree.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:263:10)
>       at Object.exports.XML (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:593:13)
>       at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/xml-helpers.js:111:38)
>       at Object.config_parser (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/config_parser.js:25:20)
>       at Object.platform (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:65:15)
>       at LocalBuildCommand.module.exports.addPlatform (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:153:13)

I am using phonegap 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little late but I just had this problem and solved it.

I just deleted the android folder in 'platforms' and reran

`phonegap run android`

you can also do `phonegap add android` if you don't want to run it.

Make sure to back up your xml manifests if you made any changes.

Comment: Yup, I had missed the phonegap add android. Fixed it a long time ago though :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way is:

1) `$ phonegap platform rm android`

2) `$ phonegap plaftorm add android`

3) `$ phonegap build android`

It is also recommended to do this when you add or remove plugin.